# How to fix expression for eval() for trailing parenthesis at the end?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a valid mathematical expression that just needs to be ended with some closing parentheses for eval() to work. For this, I can find the unclosed parentheses in the expression and append closing parentheses until the unclosed parentheses match with the closing parentheses.

This is what I have done:

```
let expression = `3 * 1 * (4 - 1 - (5 * 9 * (2 - 6 / 5 + (4 - 1 - (5 * 9 * (2 - 6 / 5 - 
                  (4 - 1 - (5 * 9 * (2 - 6 / 5 + (4 - 1 - (5 * 9 * (2 - 6 / 5`;

const openingParenthesisCount = (expression.match(/[(]/g) || []).length;
const closingParenthesisCount = (expression.match(/[)]/g) || []).length;
let unclosedParenthesisCount =
  openingParenthesisCount - closingParenthesisCount;

try {
  console.log(eval(expression));
} catch (error) {
  // Append closing parentheses until all the parentheses are closed
  while (unclosedParenthesisCount) {
    expression += ")";
    unclosedParenthesisCount--;
  }
}

// Valid expression
console.log(eval(expression));
```

I have used a test expression for this and it works, but if the expression is longer, it may take some time (but eventually will show the result).

Is there an easier/ faster method to achieve this?

Comment: *"it may take some time"* - a negligible amount of time. You could use [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) instead to create the correct number of parenthesis to append and get rid of the try-catch and simply append the parenthesis and then parse / run it, no need to try-catch.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using built-in functionality of [String#repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and use single loop instead of RegExp.

```js
const openedCount = Array.from(expression).reduce(
  (opened, curChar)=> {
    if (curChar === '(') opened++
    else if (curChar === ')') opened--
    
    return opened
  },
  0
)

expression += ')'.repeat(openedCount)
```

Comment: Is Array.from() and .reduce() necessary?
Can't we use for...of loop?

Comment: @sks6174 no that's not necessary. But imho it's better encapsulate such minor calculation